# Can a Schottky diode rectify thermal noise from a resistor working at the same temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, electrical-resistance, semiconductor-physics

I have proof that an all-hot thermionic diode can do it (see my article "Diode Rectifies Thermal Noise" in Research Gate), but no proof in this case. (Please do not rely on the Second Law of Thermodynamics - I present a counterexample in the above mentioned article).

Comment: Frankly, I think you are mistaking the purpose of this site, and writing a misleading question title is a bit unfair....flagged

Comment: *"Please do not rely on the Second Law of Thermodynamics"* - asking us to answer a question about physics without relying on an established principle of physics is off-topic as non-mainstream.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is basically "I have already established in my previous paper that a certain type of system can violate the 2nd law of thermodynamics. Now my question is: Can this *other* system *also* violate the 2nd law of thermodynamics?" The answer is, no system at all can violate the 2nd law of thermodynamics, and your previous paper is wrong. It's wrong specifically because you neglect that, just as thermal fluctuations create electrical noise in the resistor, they also create electrical noise in the diode, and the detailed properties and consequences of this noise are not obvious. [This paper](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1209/epl/i1998-00470-4/fulltext/44302.html) is a good place to start.

Comment: Thermal noise of an all-hot thermionic diode, contact potential difference and the Schottky effect (change of work function caused by an electric field) have all been taken into account. My article "Diode Rectifies Thermal Noise" is CORRECT.